# JavaScript. Fusionar 2 arreglos de objetos validando condición

Tags: array, javascript-objeto

Tengo 2 arreglos que requiero fusionar según el número de orden en cada objeto. Si el arreglo **uno.ord** es **igual** al arreglo **dos.orden** entonces pasar los datos del primer arreglo al segundo, si uno.ord y dos.orden son diferentes entonces los campos de uno pasarían como vacíos al arreglo dos.

```
uno = [
    {
        "ord": 971,
        "fecha": "2023-10-11",
        "costo": 0.33,
        "notas": [],
        "total_notas": 0
    }
];

dos = [
    {
        "marca": "RST",
        "fecha_aut": "2022-12-13",
        "parte": "HARDWARE",
        "orden": 989,
        "promedio": 0.17
    },
    {
        "marca": "RST",
        "fecha_aut": "2023-10-10",
        "parte": "WB"
        "orden": 971,
        "promedio": 0.69
    }
];
```

El resultado buscado es el siguiente:

```
resultado  = [
    {
        "marca": "RST",
        "fecha_aut": "2022-12-13",
        "parte": "HARDWARE",
        "orden": 989,
        "promedio": 0.17,
        "ord": ,
        "fecha": ,
        "costo": ,
        "notas": [],
        "total_notas": 
    },
    {
        "marca": "RST",
        "fecha_aut": "2023-10-10",
        "parte": "WB"
        "orden": 971,
        "promedio": 0.69,
        "ord": 971,
        "fecha": "2023-10-11",
        "costo": 0.33,
        "notas": [],
        "total_notas": 0
    }
];
```

Estoy intentado por separado con cada una de las siguientes opciones:

*resultado = [uno, dos].flat();*

*resultado = {...uno, ...dos};*

*resultado = Object.assign(dos, uno);*

*resultado = uno.concat(dos);*

Pero no consigo el resultado esperado.
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda pudieran ofrecer!!!

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre iterando y ocupando Object.assign, no es lo más óptimo pero es un punto de partida quizás (asumiendo que "uno" es un arreglo de 1 elemento)

```
const new_dos = [] 

const empty_uno = { ord: null, 
                    fecha: null,
                    costo: null,
                    notas: null,
                    total_notas: null }

dos.forEach((item) => {
    if(item.orden == uno[0].ord) {
        Object.assign(item, uno[0])
    }
    else {
        Object.assign(item, empty_uno)
    }
    new_dos.push(item)
})
```